# CAAnimationGroup with different interface elements

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nswindow, caanimation

I want to crossfade two `NSViews` and resize their `NSWindow`. I know how to do them separately but so far not how to do it simultaneously. I think I need a `CAAnimationGroup` for it. But because I'm dealing with two different objects, I don't know how to add the two animations in the group and I don't know how to start the animation because I can't call `animator` on them both.

Answer (score 1):

you should use a `CATransaction` to do this. all animations are grouped with `CATransactions`, either implicitly or explicitly, check the docs for more details. Just use something like:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:whatever];

 // adjust layer properties here for required animations

[CATransaction commit];
```